# Exchange SinglePartition Error in SparkSQL Query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL 2.4 queries.
I am using the following sql which is throwing an error: The query is big and has several steps, so I have given a concise version below. When I execute the query, from the `Spark-Shell`, it fails with the error given below. The explain-plan is rather long so I have trimmed it to a more manageable extent :

I have checked that the values of the `partition by encnbr` column are fairly unique. However, the **Stages** tab in **Spark UI** shows only **1** very lengthy `task` indicating `SKEW`. However, since the keys are unique, I'm not sure why this is happening. I have tried using `cluster by encnbr` in vain.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:

Exchange SinglePartition

+-  *(79) LocalLimit 4
    +- *(79) Project [enc_key#976, prsn_key#951, prov_key#952, clm_key#977, clm_ln_key#978... 7 more fields]
       +- Window [lag(non_keys#2862, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(encnbr#2722, eff_dt#713 ASC NULLS FIRST, data_timestamp#2723 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(Rowframe, -1, -1)) AS _we0#2868], [encnbr#2722], [eff_dt#713 ASC NULLS FIRST, data_timestamp#2723 ASC NULLS FIRST]......
```

The query consists of several steps with one depending on the result from the previous. However, the step which is failing is something similar to :

```
select
enc_key,
prsn_key,
prov_key,
clm_key,
clm_ln_key
birth_dt,
case when lag(non_keys) over (partition by encnbr order by eff_dt asc, data_timestamp asc) is null
     then 'Y'
     when lag(non_keys) <> non_keys
     then 'Y'
     else 'N'
end as mod_flg
FROM (
      select
      enc_key,
      encnbr,
      prsn_key,
      prov_key,
      clm_key,
      clm_ln_key
      birth_dt,
      eff_dt,
      data_timestamp,
      md5(enc_key || prsn_key || prov_key || clm_key || clm_ln_key) as non_keys
      from 
      table1
      where encnbr is not null

      union all

      select
      enc_key,
      encnbr,
      prsn_key,
      prov_key,
      clm_key,
      clm_ln_key
      birth_dt,
      eff_dt,
      data_timestamp,
      md5(enc_key || prsn_key || prov_key || clm_key || clm_ln_key) as non_keys
      from 
      table2
      where encnbr is not null
   )
```

Can you please help me alleviate this issue. I have tried using `cluster by encnbr` in the previous step but it still keeps on failing.

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: u need to show more error info, not enuff...

Comment: Wouldn't `...when lag(non_keys) <> non_keys...` without a window spec cause the whole dataset to be collected to a single partition?

Comment: @mazaneicha gotcha.. you are absolutely right. There should be a window-spec. I had completely missed that...thank you so much.. Btw, could you please post your comments as an Answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The solution to a problem caused by typo won't benefit anyone but the author :))